# Graphviz (DOT) Captions

Tags: graphviz, dot

I need to print a large number of graphs using Graphviz DOT. To distinguish which input each graph corresponds to, I want to also have a caption for each graph. Is there anyway to embed this into the DOT representation of the graphs.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `label` to add a caption to the graph.

Example:

```
digraph {
    A -> B;
    label="Graph";
    labelloc=top;
    labeljust=left;
}
```

`labelloc`  and `labeljust` can be used to determine top/bottom and left/right position of the graph label.

All the details and other attributes that can be used to modify the label (font etc) in the [graphviz attribute reference](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:label).

Tip: Define the graph label end of your dot file, otherwise subgraphs will inherit those properties.

Answer (score 11):

Graph's can have attributes just like nodes and edges do:

```
digraph {
    graph [label="The Tale of Two Cities", labelloc=t, fontsize=30];
    node [color=blue];
    rankdir = LR;
    London -> Paris;
    Paris -> London;
}
```

That dot file produces [this graph](http://interactive.blockdiag.com/graphviz/?src=ZGlncmFwaCB7CiAgICBncmFwaCBbbGFiZWw9IlRoZSBUYWxlIG9mIFR3byBDaXRpZXMiLCBsYWJlbGxvYz10LCBmb250c2l6ZT0zMF07CiAgICBub2RlIFtjb2xvcj1ibHVlXTsKICAgIHJhbmtkaXIgPSBMUjsKICAgIExvbmRvbiAtPiBQYXJpczsKICAgIFBhcmlzIC0-IExvbmRvbjsKfQoK).

[image]

Comment: link doesn't work anymore. Could consider attaching them image directly.

Comment: Thank you for this, it is just what I needed

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to add a caption to a Graph object of graphviz in python. Then the following code can help:

```
from graphviz import Graph
dot = Graph()
dot.node('1','1')
dot.node('2','2')
dot.edge('1','2', label="link")

dot.attr(label="My caption")
dot.attr(fontsize='25')

dot.render(view=True)
```

Output:

[image: output]